# How to make an entire google sheet view only for everyone but the owner from 10:30am - 1:00pm Monday through Thursday

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sign up sheet for lunches that I would like to lock/make view-only during the lunch period (10:30am - 1:00pm) on Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday and Thursday. I would like it to be editable for anyone with the link at all other times of the week. I am a novice on adding macros and triggers to Google Sheets so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. This question is not a good fit for this site because the questions don't include enough details and are not specific enough. Please [edit] your question to describe the relevant parts of your spreadsheet, including the spreadsheet locale (country), as it affects date/time format and formula syntax. Also, mention your programming experiences and JavaScript knowledge. More guidance might be provided later.